# wysihtml5 relative url in image

Tags: javascript, url, wysiwyg, wysihtml5

i'm trying to allow relative urls in images src attribute as well as absolute ones. I can't get this done. If the parser rule setting for "src" is "url" only absolute urls are allowed and all the relative ones are stripped. If i set it to href all src attributes are thrown away. Somehow this happens on sending.

I thought href would be the right parser rule as mentioned in the docs.

Here is the description from https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/blob/master/parser_rules/advanced.js

```
 - href:           allows something like "mailto:bert@foo.com", "http://google.com", "/foobar.jpg"
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is quite an old question but hopefully this will be useful to someone else.

I had this same issue using wysihtml5-0.3.0. The "src" method appears to have been removed so setting "src": "src" in the parser rules wasn't working for me. To remedy this, as well as setting "src" : "src" in the parser rules, I've updated the the wysihtml5-x.x.x.js file by adding the following to "var attributeCheckMethods":

```
src: (function () {
    return function (attributeValue) {
        return attributeValue;
    }
})()
```

This will allow the src to be returned exactly as it was entered. This introduce a risk if it's operating in an insecure environment. The particular system I'm building has restricted access to just a handful of people so it's not an issue for me but if you want to use this publicly you may want to validate with a regular expression first.

Hope this is of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parser rule like:

```
"img": {
    "check_attributes": {
        "width": "numbers",
        "alt": "alt",
        "src": "src", // https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5/blob/master/parser_rules/advanced.js#L97
        "height": "numbers"
    },
    "add_class": {
        "align": "align_img"
    }
},
```